# Retrieve n-level deep sub-document in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a deeply nested document in mongoDB and I would like to fetch individual sub-objects.

Example:

```
{
   "schoolName": "Cool School",
   "principal": "Joe Banks",
   "rooms": [
      {
         "number": 100
         "teacher": "Alvin Melvin"
         "students": [
            {
               "name": "Bort"
               "currentGrade": "A"
            },
            // ... many more students
         ]
      },
      // ... many more rooms
   ]
}
```

Recently Mongo updated to allow 1-level-deep sub-object retrieval using [$elemMatch projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/):

```
var projection = { _id: 0, rooms: { $elemMatch: { number: 100 } } };
db.schools.find({"schoolName": "Cool School"}, projection);
// returns { "rooms": [ /* array containing only the matching room */ ]  }
```

But when I try to fetch a student (2 levels deep) in this same fashion, I get an error:

```
var projection = { _id: 0, "rooms.students": { $elemMatch: { name: "Bort" } } };
db.schools.find({"schoolName": "Cool School"}, projection);
// "$err": "Cannot use $elemMatch projection on a nested field (currently unsupported).", "code": 16344
```

**Is there a way to retrieve arbitrarily deep sub-objects in a mongoDB document?**

I am using Mongo 2.2.1

Comment: Matching arbitrarily nested subdocuments is not supported by the positional operator or `$elemMatch`.  You can vote/watch [SERVER-831](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831) which is a feature request for "Positional Operator Matching Nested Arrays".

Answer (score 3):

I recently asked a similar question and can provide a suitably general answer (see [Using MongoDB's positional operator $ in a deeply nested document query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676481/using-mongodbs-positional-operator-in-a-deeply-nested-document-query))

This solution is only supported for Mongo 2.6+, but from then you can use the aggregation framework's $redact function.

Here is an example query which should return just your student Bort.

```
db.users.aggregate({

    $match: { schoolName: 'Cool School' }

}, {

    $project: {

        _id: 0,
        'schoolName': 1,
        'rooms.number': 1,
        'rooms.students': 1

    }

}, {

    $redact: {
        $cond: {
            "if": {
                $or: [{
                    $gte: ['$schoolName', '']
                }, {
                    $eq: ['$number', 100]
                }]
            },
            "then": "$$DESCEND",
            "else": {
                $cond: {
                    "if": {
                        $eq: ['$name', 'Bort']
                    },
                    "then": "$$KEEP",
                    "else": "$$PRUNE"
                }
            }
        }
    }

});
```

$redact can be used to make sub-queries by matching or pruning sub-documents recursively in the matched documents.

[You can read about $redact here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) to understand more about what's going on but the design pattern I've identified has the following requirements:

- The redact condition is applied at **each** sub-document level so you need a unique field at each level e.g. you can't have number as a key on both rooms and students say
- It only works on data fields not array indices so if you want to know the returned position of a nested document ([for example to update it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173482/mongodb-update-deeply-nested-subdocument)) you need to include that and maintain it in your documents
- Each part of the **$or** statement in $redact should match the documents you want at a specific level
- Therefore each part of the **$or** statement needs to include a match to the unique field of the document at that level. For example, `$eq: ['$number', 100]` matches the room with number 100
- If you aren't specifying a query at a level, you need to still include the unique field. For example, if it is a string you can match it with `$gte: ['$uniqueField': '']`
- The last document level goes in the **second** if expression so that all of that document is kept.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have mongodb 2.2 handy at the moment, so I can't test this, but have you tried?

```
var projection = { _id: 0, rooms: { $elemMatch: { "students.name": "Bort" } } };
db.schools.find({"schoolName": "Cool School"}, projection);
```

Comment: Ah, that query matches but unfortunately returns the "room" object that contains "Bort" where I'd like the "student" object.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like its not supported yet. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/projection.cpp#L73 (pretty nasty `! mongoutils::str::contains( e.fieldName(), '.' )`)