# Updating/Adding Sub-Document on Sub Document in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How to updating/adding sub-document in sub-document in mongoose,
I have sample data for Tree Json, like this:

```
orgchart:
 [
  {
    level: 0,
    name: Division 0,
    child: [
     {
       level: 1,
       nama: Division 1,
       child: [
        {
          level: 2,
          nama: Sub Division 2,
          child: [ here division X ]
        }
       ]
     }
  },
 ]
```

I tried use parent.push but only add 1 sub document, when i tried to use more sub document in sub document always failed with message "TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined"

Do you have clue for this problem,
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code or the query you're performing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to bother you mr tsturzl
I got solution from [Mongodb update deeply nested subdocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173482/mongodb-update-deeply-nested-subdocument)

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In this case you're probably best off grabbing calling `.findOne()` to get the document contain the sub-document that you want to update, pushing the subdocument to the array, then calling `.save()` on the document.

Really, if you have sub-documents with embedded sub-documents, you should consider creating a collection for the sub documents, and possibly the documents embedded in those sub-documents. You can store `_id` references in the parent document and invoke `populate(...)` with your query.

I would provide an example, though I'm not certain what you're trying to accomplish. Initially it looks like bad data modeling, but I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish.