# Issue: updating value inside the subdocument of a subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am having some trouble trying to update some fields of a subdocument inside a subdocument in `mongodb`.

First of all, let's find exactly the document I need to update to see how the document structure looks like:

```
// query:
db.getCollection('collection').find({
    application: ObjectId("568b3a2feaa4171d03734776"),
    _id: ObjectId("568b3a2feaa4171d03734779"),
    status: 'sent',
    'mailingList.recipients.email': 'example@example.com' // an index
},
{
    'mailingList.$.recipients': true
});

// query result:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("568b3a2feaa4171d03734779"),
    "mailingList" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 55,
            "recipients" : [ 
                {
                    "metadata" : {
                        "name" : "Example",
                        "surname" : "Example"
                    },
                    "email" : "example@example.com",
                    "message" : {
                        "events" : []
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I would like to achieve is exactly being able to **update** any of the fields in the object inside `recipients[]`: let's say, for example, `email`. I've tried the following so far, using the `$set` operator:

```
db.getCollection('collection').update({
    application: ObjectId("568b3a2feaa4171d03734776"),
    _id: ObjectId("568b3a2feaa4171d03734779"),
    status: 'sent',
    'mailingList.recipients.email': 'example@example.com'
},
{
    $set: {
        'mailingList.$.recipients.email': 'newmail@example.com'
    }
});
```

but I get the following **error**:

> cannot use the part (recipients of mailingList.1.recipients.email) to
>   traverse the element ({recipients: [ { metadata: { name: "Example",
>   surname: "Example" }, email: "example@example.com", message: { events:
>   [] } } ]})

What am I missing? I had already worked with embedded subdocuments before (not like this where there is a subdocument inside another subdocument) and using `$set` was enough to update any field inside a single subdocument, i.e:

```
$set: {
    'mailingList.$.email': 'newmail@gmail.com'
}
```

Comment: I too have seen examples where $ is the last character in set field e.g. abc.xyz.$ but never got abc.$.xyz to update.