# How to update deep array in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am using mongoose in nodejs...
I want to update deep array but cant update properly..
schema of this field is below...

```
case : [{
visit : [{
          visit_no : Number,
          treat : {
          rep : [{name : String,img :{type : String,match : /^http:\/\//i}}]
          }
}]}]
```

I had applied query with the help of https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831 is shown below...

```
update({"_id" : fields.id,"case._id" : fields.case,"case.visit._id" : fields.visit,"case.visit.treat.rep._id" : req.body.PInv},{$set : {"case.$0.visit.$1.treat.rep.$2.img" : req.body.img}})
```

But is will not showing error nor giving proper error..
i will require help for this problem

Answer (score 0):

It could have something to do with mongoose not allowing you to use the $ operator more than once per key. Check out using the [DocumentArray.id(id)](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_documentarray_MongooseDocumentArray.id) method to search subdocuments. Check out Noam El's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173482/mongodb-update-deeply-nested-subdocument) question. It might help you out to do a findById() on the outermost document before using the above method.

Hope this helps point you in the right direction!