# How to update mongoose nested array document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I know the question is duplicate but I dont know Why I am stuck

**Question**:

How can I edit `"requirement.$.update"` array documents, using find by `_id` and `requirement.update._id`  (and if needed `requirement._id` )

```
// edit version number level2
  exports.editVersionNumberPost = function(req, res){ 
    var query = {
            date: req.body.date,
            number: req.body.number,
            description: req.body.description 
        }
    Project.findOneAndUpdate({ name:  req.params.name, 
                               "requirement._id" : req.params.versionID, 
                               "requirement.update._id" : req.params.versionNumID},  
        {"$set": 
            {"requirement.$.update" :  query 
        }   
        },  { new: true }, 
        function(err, obj){})
 };
```

**my Schema**

```
----------------
    namr: String
    requirement:[{
        version: Number,
        update:[{
            date: Date,
            number: Number,
            description: String
        }]
    }],
--------
```

Comment: Well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577123/updating-a-nested-array-with-mongodb)

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Still coudnt find a solution , Do you have time to check this ?

Comment: What issue you are facing? Please update your question with some explanation and what is not working for you.

Comment: Updated, please check now @AnthonyWinzlet

Comment: and please  I do not prefer using "index" value to the target

Comment: Hmm. Yet another person pointed to an existing answer ( link in first comment )  who did not read beyond the first block of code. If you actually **read** it, then that "first block" actually comes with the explanation that using a **hard index value, is not how to do it**. The other resounding message other than the MongoDB 3.6 available solution is that **nested arrays are a really bad idea**. I suggest actually reading the content rather than just looking for code to "cargo cult". You might learn something useful. Also please don't comment with "please help" on answers to others questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below query

```
db.getCollection("test").updateOne(
  { "name":  req.params.name },
  { "$set": { "requirement.$[outer].update.$[inner].number": 100000 } },
  {
    "arrayFilters": [
      { "outer._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.versionID) },
      { "inner._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.versionNumID) }
    ]
  }
)
```

Comment: Can we add another level too? like 1-outer, 2-inner, 3-other

Comment: @BinaraMedawatta Please ask a new question if you have further doubts