# Using MongoDB's positional operator $ in a deeply nested document query

Tags: mongodb, nested, positional-operator

Is it possible to use positional operator '$' in combination with a query on a deeply-nested document array?

Consider the following nested document defining a 'user':

```
{
   username: 'test',
   kingdoms: [

      {
          buildings: [

              {
                  type: 'castle'

              },
              {
                  type: 'treasury'
              },

              ...

          ]

      },

      ...

   ] 
}
```

We'd like to return the 'castles' for a particular user e.g. in a form:

```
{
    kingdoms: [{

        buildings: [{

            type: 'castle'

        }]

    }]
}
```

Because you cannot use the $ operator twice (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/server-831) I know that I can't also query for a particular kingdom, so I'm trying to write a find statement for the nth kingdom.

This seems to make sense when updating a deeply-nested sub-document ([Mongodb update deeply nested subdocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173482/mongodb-update-deeply-nested-subdocument)) but I'm having less success with the find query.

I can return the first kingdom's buildings with the query:

```
db.users.findOne(
    { username: 'test' },
    { kingdoms: {$slice: [0, 1]}, 'kingdom.buildings': 1 }
);
```

But this returns **all** the buildings of that kingdom.

Following the single-level examples of position operator I'm trying a query like this:

```
db.users.findOne(
    { username: 'test', 'kingdoms.buildings.type': 'castle' },
    { kingdoms: {$slice: [n, 1]}, 'kingdom.buildings.$': 1 }
);
```

so as to be in the form:

```
db.collection.find( { <array.field>: <value> ...}, { "<array>.$": 1 } )
```

as described in the documentation [http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj.*S*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_)

However this fails with the error:

```
Positional operator does not match the query specifier
```

Presumably because kingdoms.buildings isn't considered an array. I've also tried **kingdoms.0.buildings**

It is confusing because this appears to work for updates (according to [Mongodb update deeply nested subdocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173482/mongodb-update-deeply-nested-subdocument))

Have I just got the syntax wrong or is this not supported? If so is there a way to achieve something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get an error from

```
db.users.findOne(
    { username: 'test', 'kingdoms.buildings.type': 'castle' },
    { kingdoms: {$slice: [n, 1]}, 'kingdom.buildings.$': 1 }
);
```

because there is a spelling mistake ("kingdom.buildings.$" should be "kingdom**s**.buildings.$").
However, this way can not accomplish what you expect.
**$** is always aimed at **kingdoms** in the path of **kingdoms.buildings** - the first array.

This is a way that should be able to solve the problem.
(V2.6+ required)

```
db.c.aggregate([ {
    $match : {
        username : 'test',
        'kingdoms.buildings.type' : 'castle'
    }
}, {
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        kingdoms : 1
    }
}, {
    $redact : {
        $cond : {
            "if" : {
                $or : [ {
                    $gt : [ "$kingdoms", [] ]
                }, {
                    $gt : [ "$buildings", [] ]
                }, {
                    $eq : [ "$type", "castle" ]
                } ]
            },
            "then" : "$$DESCEND",
            "else" : "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }
} ]).pretty();
```

---

To only reserve the first element of **kingdoms**,

```
db.c.aggregate([ {
    $match : {
        username : 'test',
        'kingdoms.buildings.type' : 'castle'
    }
}, {
    $redact : {
        $cond : {
            "if" : {
                $or : [ {
                    $gt : [ "$kingdoms", [] ]
                }, {
                    $gt : [ "$buildings", [] ]
                }, {
                    $eq : [ "$type", "castle" ]
                } ]
            },
            "then" : "$$DESCEND",
            "else" : "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind : "$kingdoms"
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id",
        kingdom : {
            $first : "$kingdoms"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id",
        kingdoms : {
            $push : "$kingdom"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        kingdoms : 1
    }
} ]).pretty();
```

Comment: Thanks Wizard - is it possible to specify these conditions at different levels of the hierarchy simply? Say for argument a kingdom had a key `type: "castle"` then it would $$DESCEND even though it isn't matching a building's type? (or a similar situation if that example isn't valid)

Comment: @Hugheth, not very clear about your point. Can you post a document to describe it?

Comment: The main difference between this answer and _my_ use case is that it doesn't filter to a single kingdom - instead it returns all the castles of the user

Comment: @Hugheth, Do you mean you just want to return one element of **kingdoms** field? Then which one you want to return, the first one?

Comment: Yes, though it would be good to have a general answer for the nth kingdom ie. any particular kingdom

Comment: @Hugheth, Just updated it. To return the n-th kingdom, it should be something different between kingdoms using to select. If they are the structures as the question, returning anyone is equivalent.

Comment: @Hugheth, **$redact** walks all hierarchies sharing the same condition, that is why I use an **$or** clause to make sure it can walk to the bottom - {type:"castle"}. If your document structure is more complicated with more conditions, the **$or** may be more complicated.

Comment: thanks for the help. I guess an explicit **'position'** field in the kingdom documents would solve the position problem - this also has the added benefit that I can update the returned castles. All our sub-documents also have **unique primary key field names** e.g. kingdoms have kingdom_id and buildings have building_id so I hopefully I can use $exists inside the $redact conditions to ensure they only apply at a certain level of the hierarchy.